# Removing commented dead code without removing the legitimate comments

Tags: c++, c, regex, bash, grammar

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54132043/7347631) is the real question asked on StackOverflow. I'm here to review my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54133230/7347631) and see how can I optimize it.

---

#### Here is the answer text:

This is a basic approach, but it proposes a proof of concept of what might be done. I do it using Bash along with the usage of the [GCC `-fsyntax-only` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options).

Here is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    LINE=`echo $line | grep -oP "(?<=//).*"`
    if [[ -n "$LINE" ]]; then
            echo $LINE | gcc -fsyntax-only -xc -
            if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
                   sed -i "/$LINE/d" ./$1
            fi
    fi
done < "$1"
```

The approach I followed here was reading each line from the code file. Then, `grep`ing the text after the `//` delimiter *(if exists)* with the regex `(?<=//).*` and passing that to the `gcc -fsyntax-only` command **to check whether it's a correct C/C++ statement or not**. Notice that I've used the argument `-xc -` to pass the input to GCC from stdin *([see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47999843/7347631) to understand more)*. An **important** note, the `c` in `-xc -` specifies the language, which is C in this case, if you want it to be C++ you shall change it to `-xc++`.

Then, if GCC was able to successfully parse the statement (i.e., it's a legitimate C/C++ statement), I directly remove it using `sed -i` from the file passed.

---

Running it on your example (*but after removing `<- commented code` from the third line to make it a legitimate statement*):

```
// Those parameters control foo and bar... <- valid comment
int t = 5;
// int t = 10;
int k = 2*t;
```

Output (in the same file):

```
// Those parameters control foo and bar... <- valid comment
int t = 5;
int k = 2*t;
```

*(if you want to add your modifications in a different file, just remove the `-i` from `sed -i`)*

The script can be called just like: `./script.sh file.cpp`, it may show several GCC errors while these are the correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `echo | grep` is unwarranted. `bash` understands regular expressions (`"$line" =~ regex`), and can do simple substitutions: `line=${line#[[:space:]]*\/\/}` removes leading whitespaces , followed by the comment, just what we are after.
- Replacing the file while reading it looks suspiciously. I recommend to have a destination file, and copy valid lines (and don't copy undesired ones). A perk benefit is that forking `sed` is not needed anymore.

A side note: the script makes a false positive in cases like

```
    // Notice that
    // some_valid_c_code;
    // doesn't work, because etc
```

The part of the comment would be recognized as a dead code, and the output will be

```
    // Notice that
    // doesn't work, because etc
```

Comment: Your side note, you mean the code is going to remove all of the comments?

Comment: @AndrewNaguib No. See edit

Comment: Yeah, true. But, who would write a comment in such a way (i.e., "some_valid_c_code;"? :)

Comment: I mean, that is the question actually. The OP wants to remove dead code? What am I missing here?

Comment: @AndrewNaguib Me, for starters. And I've seen it in the wild. That is quite a good way to explain some not-so-obvious design decisions.

Comment: How can I use the [`=~ `](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) (side note: you have them reversed in the answer) if it's a binary operator? I actually `grep` to get the line following the `//` delimiter.

Comment: @AndrewNaguib Thanks for pointing the typo; fixed. The operator returns 0 or 1 depending on match success or failure. Use it in `if [[ "$line" =~ regex]]`.

Comment: Indeed, it is not possible to know 100% of the time for sure if a line is code or not. As such, after applying such script, one should validate each changes before committing them to source control. And even if a line is code, it might be a part of a comment and should not be deleted (for. example a line after `// Uncomment next line to enable logging`). If next line is removed, then the comment won't make sense anymore.

Answer (score 3):

#### Look for corner cases

This command is fragile, there are several ways in which it can malfunction:

> ```
> sed -i "/$LINE/d" ./$1
> ```

For example:

- If the dead code contains `/`, it will break the `sed` command, because `/` within `/.../d` must be escaped.
- It doesn't target accurately the line to remove. It removes all lines that match `$LINE`. If there are lines in the file that are similar enough to a dead code that appears somewhere else, it will be removed too.

Both of these problems can be fixed by tracking the line numbers that should be deleted, and then using those with the `d` command of `sed`, instead of pattern matching.

---

The pattern `"(?<=//).*"` used by the `grep` is not strict enough,
and may incorrectly match lines that are not dead code, for example:

> ```
> int x = 1;  // some comment
> char * s = "foo // bar";
> ```

#### Double-quote variables used in command line arguments

How many bugs can you spot here?

> ```
> while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
>     somecmd ./$1
> done < "$1"
> ```

I see at least:

- It doesn't handle absolute paths correctly. When `$1` is an absolute path, then `./$1` and `"$1"` are likely different files, except in the lucky case when the working directory is `/`.
- `./$1` is not properly quoted, so if `$1` contains spaces or shell meta-characters, the command will fail.

The solution is simple: quote properly and use the same path consistently `somecmd "$1"`.

In addition, it's usually a good idea to assign command line arguments to variables with descriptive names at the top of a script, and then refer to it by that name, instead of have `$1` scattered at multiple places in the script.

#### Use the exit code of commands directly in conditional statements

Instead of this:

> ```
> somecmd
> if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
>        ...
> fi
> ```

You can write:

```
if somecmd; then
       ...
fi
```

Simpler and quite natural!

#### Avoid `sed -i ... somefile` in a loop

Repeatedly rewriting the content of a file in a loop,
looks dangerous.

#### Use here-strings

Usually `echo "..." | somecommand` can be rewritten as `somecommand <<< "..."`,
using here-strings, and saving an `echo` and a pipe.

Then depending on `somecommand`, better options may be available,
such as using `[[ ... =~ ... ]]` for pattern matching instead of `grep` (as @vnp mentioned),
or running `grep` on a larger outer scope (as demonstrated in the previous point).

#### Alternative implementation

Consider this alternative implementation that fixes the above issues and bad practices.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

input=$1

sed_commands=()
line_num=1
while IFS= read -r line || [[ "$line" ]]; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^[[:space:]]+// ]]; then
        if gcc -fsyntax-only -xc - <<< "$line"; then
            sed_commands+=(-e "${line_num}d")
        fi
    fi
    ((line_num++))
done < "$input"

sed "${sed_commands[@]}" -i "$input"
```

The weakness of this alternative is that if there are enough dead code lines in the input, then the maximum argument count limit of the shell may be reached in the final `sed` command. When that becomes a realistic issue, it can be optimized to handle that.